# Running subprocess module in UEFI Shell

Tags: python, shell, uefi

I want to run a command in UEFI shell and capture the output in a variable but not to file, please help me to use subprocess module in UEFI Shell..

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
command >v Variablename
```